# Can VM's use more than one node in Ubuntu Cloud?

Tags: virtualization, cloud

Can a Virtual Machine, instantiated in the Ubuntu Cloud (UEC), use resources from more than one node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"use resources from more than one node"

If by resources, you mean:

- cpu
- memory
- network

Then the answer is definitely 'no'.

If you mean 'disk', then the answer is "sort of".

You can use remote disk resources with EBS disk (elastic block store).